# Zotero in chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, zotero

I have migrated from Firefox to Chrome and i am unable to download the citation entries directly to zotero using chrome. How to make it work, as firefox does.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the Chrome and Safari too :

Thanks to :[zotero to chrome and safari](http://www.zotero.org/support/kb/httpserver_enabled)
For ***Zotero 2.1.x***: Type about:config in the address bar of Firefox and search for “connector”. You'll want to double-click on the entry connector.enabled and restart Firefox. Enabling this preference may interfere with saving to Zotero Standalone, if both are installed.

For ***Zotero 3.0*** and higher: Type about:config in the address bar of Firefox and search for “zotero.httpServer”. You'll want to double-click on the entry extensions.zotero.httpServer.enabled and restart Firefox.

Then install the connector in the other browser (Chrome or Safari) and also restart this browser. Now the Save to Zotero icon should show up in that browser too, and clicking it will result in the item being saved in the Zotero library in Firefox.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work in my system. Have you tried with chrome?

Comment: Which version of Zotero are you using?

Comment: I have downloaded Zotero connector and its not working with chrome. It says its installed but, can not find any button / tool in the chrome menu.